# In Symfony, how to remove the query string from the uri in the browser

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

In my multilingual Symfony (2.8) application, I have a number of views that are injected into a main page using ajax. Based on this [article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html) I have implemented a locale listener, so the locale is sticky.

I found that quitting and restarting the browser (Safari) while the main is page open – while the current locale is **not** the default – that the current locale on the very next `request` is lost, since there is now no previous session. When a view from an ajax link is returned, the locale is set to the default, resulting in a page with mixed languages.

As a workaround, I am including the current locale as a query on all ajax links and I have hijacked the locale listener, which can now set the locale on the `request` from the query, even under the circumstances described above.

It appears to do the job. However, the downside is that I'm now left with ugly urls that include the query string, e.g. `www.domain.co.uk/es/moreinfo?_locale=es`.

I've been trying to implement another listener, to strip the query from the uri. The listener detects the query and can remove it from the `request->query` parameter and the `$_SERVER` globals, but nothing I try makes it change when the view comes back to the browser.

I've also tried using new routes, which resolve and forward or redirect to a different route/path, but still the url in the browser remains unchanged.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Am I going about this from the wrong angle - i.e. should I try doing it client-side, rather than server-side?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, there is also a locale specified in your url like this: `{url}/{_locale}/moreinfo...`.

It is correct approach for localization. The only thing you need now is to suit Symfony locale to `_locale` slug in your url. As you probably guess, `_locale` query parameter is redundant then.

Refer this SO question for complete solution.

Comment: Yes, that would seem to be the right approach. However, the `{url}/{_locale}` path is set from the main route, the Ajax route has the path `/moreinfo`. So the `{_locale}` slug is not available when the `/moreinfo` route is matched.

Comment: You could set locale to your request anywhere using `$request->setLocale($locale)`. After that you could access it using `$request->getLocale()`. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Well, that is precisely what the listener does, except that it has to get the value of `$locale` from somewhere. In the situation I describe that value doesn't exist, which is why I'm setting it from a query. Otherwise it just gets the default locale value, `en`. I'm starting to think ill just have to parse the locale from the url, something I was hoping to avoid.